# Problem in Capturing image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image

Plz tell me dat is it possible?
if there is running many app in background in iPhone
 and now I open my app
entering the some info in form page and start the camera to capture the image
after capturing the image, form UI was mismanaged

Comment: Um, what? You'll have to be clearer.

Comment: are u using iPhone camera in your own app or the external camera application?

Comment: @sanchitsingh:im using iphone camera thru my app

Comment: @Yann Ramin: actually
in background there is running various apps
and after starting my app
there is add form
in which i have to giv some informatin
and can capture the images too
4m camera & gallery
after startng the camera thru my app
capture the image
when i return from the camra after attaching the image
my add form view was mismanaged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the size of that image that you are capturing and showing in your form. This might be the issue of height and width of that image which is making your other controls improper. You can fix the size and position of all controls in your project so that all controls will remain same as they were.